# php session on page 1 and page 2

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, session-timeout

Here is my question, I have lets say 2 pages page 1 and page 2, what I need is to open session and set cookie on page 1 that will remain for 1 hour and will be reset on every page refresh. Now the page 2 story is slightly different scenario, first of all page 2 should not open any session, but instead should check if any session that was opened on page 1 is still valid and if it is than proceed further with whatever the request was and remain for the lifetime of the cookie, however, if the visitor who is visiting page 2 either directly via saved url or if page 2 is visited any time after the session cookie is expired than visitor should redirected to page 1.

here is what I have done so far on the page 1

```
<?php
function startSession($time = 3600, $ses = 'MYSES') {
    session_set_cookie_params($time);
    session_name($ses);
    session_start();

    // Reset the expiration time upon page load
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$ses]))
      setcookie($ses, $_COOKIE[$ses], time() + $time, "/");
}
?>
```

the problem is, I have no idea what to and how to do the rest and what I should have on the page 2?

here is what I have tried on page 2, but it did not work.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION));{
$a = session_id();
if(empty($a) and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);{
    header('location: page1.html');}}
?>
```

Please help guys.

Comment: At first look, i can see an error. Try to delete de semicolon after the first if: **if (!isset($_SESSION)){**

Comment: I have just done it, yet still nothing seem to be happening, not sure if the script placed on the page 1 actually works?

Comment: start your session before to use in page2..
`session_start();`

Comment: @Ranjith, I have tried it too, yet still no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax issues aside, it doesn't look like you're using $_SESSION at all, to use $_SESSION you must declare session_start() before any output. So in your case perhaps use Cookies only.

Page 1 (page1.php):

```
<?php
    function extendCookie($time = 3600) {
        setcookie('MYSES', 'dummy var', time() + $time, "/");
    }
    extendCookie(); //extend cookie by 3600 seconds (default)
?>
You are on page 1.<br />
<a href="page2.php">Click to proceed to page 2</a>
```

Page 2 (page2.php):

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['MYSES'])){
        header('location: page1.php');
    }
?>
You are on page 2.
```

If you want to use sessions, this would be the way:

Page 1 (page1.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function extendSession($time = 3600) {
        $_SESSION['expire_time'] = time() + $time;
    }
    extendSession(7200); //extend session by 7200 seconds
?>
You are on page 1.<br />
<a href="page2.php">Click to proceed to page 2</a>
```

Page 2 (page2.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION) || $_SESSION['expire_time'] < time()){
        session_destroy(); //Optional, destroy the expired session.
        header('location: page1.php');
    }
?>
You are on page 2.
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it did not work, I have exactly as you have mentioned in your example, but instead of staying on the page 2 I have been redirected back to page 1.

Comment: Sorry, fixed, I was careless. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php on how to use cookies.

Comment: for some reason, when I am trying to access page to by making a request from page 1 I still do end up on the page 1. To clarify, I am using session_start() script that you have provided.

Comment: Could it be because I changed the function name to extendSession and you're still calling the startSession?

Comment: cannot really tell why, I have used it exactly as above, but yet still no satisfactory results

Comment: Even if those are the only code on your pages? (Make sure session_start() is sent before ANY output, spaces or line breaks included)

Comment: (Sorry if you did) Did you call extendSession() on page 1 after the extendSession function?

Comment: What do you mean? Do I need to call it again? can you please update your answer, so I can actually see how? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Corrected them once more and now they should just run as is. Note I changed the extensions to .php from .html because additional configuration is needed for the server (Apache, IIS, ...) to parse HTML as PHP, and I'm not sure if you've done that.

Comment: I will give it another try later today today and will let you know how it goes. my .htaccess is configured to parse html as PHP, I have done it possibli as one of the first things about 9 years ago. :)

Comment: I have tested it and it all now works exactly as expected, thanks for helping me